# Why do companies bother paying dividends below some threshold?

Tags: dividends

There are companies out there paying dividends of fractions of a percent. Why do they bother doing that? There isn’t much an investor can do with a yield of 0.1%, even if their holdings in the company are fairly large.

Comment: Because 0.1% > 0.0%. No one gains from placing the excess capital on a bank-account, if the company cannot spend it more wisely.

Comment: If a company's ROIC is meaningful then I'd prefer they keep the money rather than spreading a few tens of millions of dollars across hundreds of thousands of shareholders. I'll probably want to reinvest those dividends, but now I have to pay taxes on them too, so they may as well have stayed with the company to begin with.

Comment: but that is prerequisite regardless of the amount. If the company’s ROIC is larger than shareholders otherwise opportunity, then they should keep the capital in the company.

Comment: There are companies like JNJ which generate a lot of cash and have good ROIC, but don't have much in the way of organic growth prospects. In that case I want them to return some of that cash to me rather than going off and acquiring/expanding the company for the sake of expanding the company.

Comment: because *expected* ROIC on re-investing it not big enough; therefore it should be paid out. If they can generate New ROIC > Old ROIC, then for sure they should keep it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of [NVIDIA](https://www.streetinsider.com/dividend_history.php?q=nvda), the company had a dividend yield of 2.6% in 2012. It doubled its cash dividend payments by 2021. However, its dividend yield is now 0.05% because its stock price has increased far more than its dividend has.

As for 0.1% being useless, I would tend to agree, although 0.1% is higher than the average savings account [rate](https://www.bankrate.com/banking/savings/average-savings-interest-rates/) in the United States.

Why hasn't NVIDIA eliminated its dividend? For longtime shareholders, the dividend yield is still substantial if calculated based on their initial investment. Further, it's considered to be bad news if a company lowers or eliminates its dividend.

Comment: Good point re: longtime shareholders potentially still getting significant yield

Comment: Yield isn't the same as interest